# Loading CSV into Pandas - no file directory

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need help debugging this code.
I am trying to add a csv file to my pandas data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('batting.csv')
print(df)
```

When I execute this code I am getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'batting.csv'
```

I then tried to change the directory using os

```
os.getcwd()
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\crack\Downloads\excel\batting.csv")
```

I am now coming across this error:

```
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\crack\\Downloads\\excel\\batting.csv'
```

I am new to coding and have been looking for a solution to this error all day.

Comment: Indeed, `...\batting.csv` is not a _directory_ - it's a file. You could try `pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\crack\Downloads\excel\batting.csv")`

Answer (score 1):

You could try ,

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\crack\Downloads\excel\batting.csv")
```

instead of
`df = pd.read_csv ('batting.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. The working directory is probably not where your file is located.

Try doing the following to see where it is:

```py
print(os.getcwd())
```

The error you are seeing using `os.chdir()` is because you have specified a filename not a directory.

You have a few possible solutions:

1. Specify the full path to your CSV file:

   ```py
   pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\crack\Downloads\excel\batting.csv")
   ```
2. Change the working directory to the same folder:

   ```py
   os.chdir(r"C:\Users\crack\Downloads\excel")
   pd.read_csv("batting.csv")
   ```
3. If the script and CSV files are in the same folder and you don't want to specify a fixed path:

   ```py
   os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
   pd.read_csv("batting.csv")
   ```

   This changes the working directory to be where the script is located. It takes the full script name and uses just the directory part.